# ¿Conoceis algun código sencillo para encender la linterna del celular? Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Buenas necesito un código sencillo para encender la linterna.

Comment: Te invito a pasar por la [Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) del sitio y leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que la tuya sea bien recibida y puedas ganar tu primera medalla.. Para poder ayudarte, debes haber intentado algo y compartir el código que llevas hecho hasta ahora, y con esto, te ayudamos a detectar errores o a mejorarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde apis arriba de la 21 podes utilizar lo siguiente

```
CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
String cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0]; // usualmente la camara delantera esta en la posicion 0
camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
```

no olvides en el manifest los permisos

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Comment: esperar a que la preguntas tengan el formato minimo requerido para responder nos ayuda a mantener la calidad del sitio.

Comment: disculpa rene, como vi que era en java y necesitaba para prender la linterna esto es con lo que puedo contribuir

Comment: Gracias por el código, lo probare y os diré si funciona correctamente.

Comment: Gracias @GastónSaillén  tu código me fue muy útil